# Example pipeline task for automated ui-tests with xamarin in appcenter, triggered from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-devops, xamarin.uitest, build-pipeline

I want to run our automated ui tests from xamarin ui-tests in appcenter.
But i don't want to start the test runs manually, but rather being triggerd by my Azure DevOps build pipelin. I already found the task for this, but unfortunately the documentation only contains a sample for espresso, and none for xamarin ui-test.
So right now i'm a bit lost on what i have to setup and what commands are really needed to get this going.
I already did successfully run the ui-tests manually on app-center, but getting this married to azure devops is a bit too much for my brain right now (maybe i just overlooked some basic things)

**[edit1]** I forgot to mention, that i (for some not know reason) cannot use the old graphical yaml builder of azure devops, but are stuck to the yaml file editor. So since the documentation for the graphical yaml builder is much better, i would also be glad if someone would show me, how i could switch back to it in azure devops.
**[/edit1]**

**[edit2]**
I think I should just open my eyes before asking a question for which the answer is directly in front of me.
so, i found the graphical yaml builder just on the right of the window :/.
I'll leave this question though and updated it with a working sample file, once i finished creating one.
If someone out there is faster than me, i'm happy to upvote and accept his answer though :).
**[/edit2]**

So, if anyone of you has a build pipeline task for automated xamarin ui-tests to help me out, i would be really greatful.

Best regards and thx in advance.
Maverick

***Update***

I now get the following error message:

```
##[error]Error: Cannot find any file based on d:\a\1\s\com.docuware.mobileclient.apk.
```

In my Publish Task the file is taken from here:

```
Upload 'd:\a\1\b\Debug' to file container: '#/9635693/drop'
```

This is the path i gave for the apk file:

```
appFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/com.companyname.filename.apk'
```

of course i see, that the file is in subfolder named "Debug", but how to tell the task to look in d:\a\1\b for debug and not in d:\a\1\s?

Comment: Maybe this can help: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/vsts-plugin#xamarinuitest) I've build mine with the help of this document.

Comment: i still have trouble with setting the correct path to the apk.
Since i use a remote build agent on azure, i cannot quite see the folder structure.